# PHP secure session throwing out users in rapid page request

Tags: php, session, session-state, login-script

using the fairly standard PHP security model from **[here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL.)**

Every page has a session regeneration function like below and a login_check function (see the url above).

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
$secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
$httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_start(); // Start the php session
session_regenerate_id(); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```

My users are having an issue if they are on a slow line and requesting pages too quickly - they are thrown out and taken back to the login page. I think it might be something with the session regeneration. Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure what's so secure about this!  ID regeneration comes at a cost so you might want to rethink how frequently you regenerate the ID.

Answer (score 0):

i use the same and never had problem....

just check if you forgot to start the

```
sec_session_start
```

somewhere ....

or you can have inverse problem...you called that function more times somewhere

Comment: I would suggest rewriting this as a full answer; at present, it is liable for deletion as it is very vague.

Comment: No only one and in every page. I can replicate the problem by refreshing the same page quick enough - when I do it quick enough I get thrown out. If I only do it once a second, no problem.